# Updating badge number every 30 minutes

Tags: swift, uilocalnotification

With this code the badge number changes to "1" when the first notification fires, but for the rest of the notifications the badge number doesn't. The notifications comes every 30 minutes, but the badge number only changes to "1" the first time. Anyone know i can rewrite this to make the badge number add 1 for each notification that fires?

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {

    let notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings(forTypes: [.Sound, .Alert, .Badge], categories: nil)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().registerUserNotificationSettings(notificationSettings)

    let reminderNote: UILocalNotification = UILocalNotification()
    reminderNote.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 60 * 30)
    reminderNote.repeatInterval = NSCalendarUnit.Hour
    reminderNote.alertBody = "some text"
    reminderNote.alertAction = "View"
    reminderNote.soundName = "sound.aif"
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(reminderNote)
    reminderNote.fireDate = NSDate(timeIntervalSinceNow: 60 * 60)
    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(reminderNote)

    reminderNote.applicationIconBadgeNumber = UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1

    UIApplication.sharedApplication().scheduleLocalNotification(reminderNote)

    return true
}
```

Comment: Where(in which method) are you resetting badge number to 0?

Comment: @AliJawad I haven't added that yet. I figured it was better to sort out this problem before adding more code.

Answer (score 0):

There is actually no API for making a recurring local notification update the badge number each time it fires. What you can do is deschedule all your previous notifications and reschedule them with the correct badge number. However, if the application is not open, you'll not be able to increase the badge number with local notifications.

Comment: But there is a max limit of scheduling 64 notifications. Any way to bypass this?

Comment: @Gjeruldsen if you are scheduling notification after every thirty minute, which means you need 48 notifications a day. For each notification you schedule, set its repeat interval daily.

Comment: _Each app on a device is limited to 64 scheduled local notifications. The system discards scheduled notifications in excess of this limit, keeping only the 64 notifications that will fire the soonest. Recurring notifications are treated as a single notification._ from [Local and Remote Notification Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/WhatAreRemoteNotif.html). The only way to bypass this limit is using recurring notifications.

Comment: @AliJawad Let's say i set up the 48 notifications and i give them a badge icon value from 1 to 48. Setting them to repeat daily will not increase the next day's first badge value notification to 49, but to start from 1 to 48 again, right?

Comment: @adrianokw Is it possible to make the recurring notifications to increase by one each time they are fired?

Comment: Have not experimented in iOS 9, but as far as I have worked with local notifiactions in iOS 8

    reminderNote.applicationIconBadgeNumber = UIApplication.sharedApplication().applicationIconBadgeNumber + 1

will always increment previous app badge number untill you set applicationBadgeNumber to zero

Comment: @Gjeruldsen Sorry, my answer wasn't really clear. I edited it to reinforce that Apple doesn't provide any methods to increase the badge number every time a recurring notification fires.